# prevent the user from entering anymore than 5 digit android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a textEdit that I want to set maxLength of 5 input digit to that and I want to do that programatically not from .xml file, would you please help me in this implementation,

before, I had a validation but now I want to have just ability of 5 digit in my edit text

```
private static boolean validateMinLength(EditText editText, int minLength) {
    if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !isRequired) {
        editText.setError(null);
        return true;
    }

    if (editText.getText().toString().length() < minLength) {
          editText.setError(String.format(context.getString(R.string.requires_at_least_five_digit) , 
 minLength));

        return false;
    } else {
        editText.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

instead of having this error hint

```
editText.setError(String.format(context.getString(R.string.requires_at_least_five_digit) , minLength));
```

I want to just enter just 5 digit and user can not enter more that 5 digit in edit text

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to set attribute android:maxLength="5" in your layout xml?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `InputFilter.LengthFilter` to the `EditText`:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `int` to whatever number you need.

In your case:

```
int maxLength = 5;    
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```